# Detect end of a live video on Android Exoplayer

Tags: android, android-video-player, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

**How do I detect the end of a live video playing in Exoplayer on Android?**

The Player.STATE_ENDED state gets called(logged) only for videos which are not live.

Comment: Did you look https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2623

Comment: Seems like it is an issue with Wowza